# What is the overall probability of success of infinite draws with exponentially decreasing odds of success per draw?

Tags: probability

If I flip a coin until I get "heads", sooner or later, I will get one occurrence and stop. Probability of success is 1.
But what if after each "tails" (failed) draw, odds for the next draw are divided by 2 ? Instead of having successive odds like 0.5, 0,5, 0.5, etc... I have 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, etc...
Is it possible to never get "heads"?

Trying to figure out this, I ran the following rust code:

```
use rand;

fn draw() -> bool {
    const MIN_MAX: f64 = 1e-20;
    let mut max = 1.0;
    while max > MIN_MAX {
        max /= 2.0;
        if rand::random::<f64>() < max {
            return true
        }
    }
    false
}

fn main() {
    const TOTAL: i32 = 10_000_000;
    let mut success = 0;
    for _ in 0..TOTAL {
        if draw() {
            success += 1;
        }
    }
    println!("{} / {}", success, TOTAL);
}
```

Some comments:

- I found an overall probability of **0.711**
- The `MIN_MAX`is the minimum value of individual draw odds at which the program gives up and return false. Changing this value between 1e-20 and 1e-40 does not change the result much.

I would be interested to know if the overall probablity is below 1, and if so, what are the fancy maths to explain the result.

**EDIT 1 2021-03-20:**

Probability to have success between 1 and n draws would be:
$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\times4}+\frac{1\times3}{2\times4\times8}+\frac{1\times3\times7}{2\times4\times8\times16}...$
(too bad at jaxmath for formula with n)
which converges to 0.7112119049133813

**EDIT 3 2021-03-20:**

Googling `7112119049`I found this:
https://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/47/science-math-philosophy/538-riddler-question-about-coin-flipping-game-1719467/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling `7112119049`, I found a discussion (and explanations) very close to this question: https://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/47/science-math-philosophy/538-riddler-question-about-coin-flipping-game-1719467/
Probablity of success is:

$1-phi(\frac{1}{2})$

where *phi* is the Euler function.

Answer (score 1):

For each positive integer $n$, let $x_n$ be the probability that experiment terminates in at most $n$ flips.

Then we have the recursion
$$
x_n=x_{n-1}+(1-x_{n-1})\Bigl({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\Bigr)^n
$$
for $n > 1$, together with the initial value $x_1={\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$.

**Claim:**$\;$For all $n$ we have 
$
{\large{\frac{1}{2}}}
\le 
x_n <
{\large{\frac{3}{4}}}
$.

**Proof:**

From the definition of $x_n$ (or from the recursion), it's immediate that $x_n\ge x_{n-1}\;$for all $n > 1$.

It follows that $x_n\ge {\large{\frac{1}{2}}}\;$for all $n$.

For the upper bound, we prove the more precise claim: 
$
x_n
\le 
{\large{\frac{3}{4}}}-{\large{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}}
$.

Proceed by induction on $n$ . . .

The base case $n=1$ is easily verified.

Next let $n > 1$ and assume the claim holds for the previous value of $n$.$\;$Then
\begin{align*}
x_n&=x_{n-1}+(1-x_{n-1})\Bigl({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\Bigr)^n
\\[4pt]
&\le
\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)
+
\Bigl(
\frac{1}{2}
\Bigr)
\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^n
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the induction.